# Flow type check for Keyed collections e.g new Set()

Tags: javascript, flowtype

I'm trying to use Flow type check on my project. I am having difficulties with finding correct type for `new Set()`

For example

`const myNumbers = new Set([123, 234, 345, 456]);`

I thought `const myNumbers: String[] = new Set([123, 234, 345, 456]);` would work, but it doesn't (-_-;)

How can I solve it?

Comment: `Set` is not `String[]`. 
Is there a `Set` type?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use `String[]` for a `Set` of numbers. Use [`Set<T>`](https://github.com/facebook/flow/blob/v0.104.0/lib/core.js#L631) instead:

```
const myNumbers: Set<number> = new Set([123, 234, 345, 456]);
```

Comment: I get an error - Cannot resolve name T.     - `selectedCheckboxes: Set<T>`

Comment: @Meilan did you use `Set<number>` or `Set<T>`? T refers to a generic type.